# unnecssary variable in my CSS, is needed to influence the appearance - what' wrong?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to draw this button in IE8 ([picture attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDui6.jpg))

I took the CSS from another source, and left only what I thought was needed.

I ended up with this line:

`.ie8 .aaa .button1{padding-right:4px;width:94px}`

the `aaa` came from the former source, and therefore is not being used in my HTML, which is:

```
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
.
.
.
<form action="a.htm" method="POST" target="_blank">
<div class="button-holder"><input type="submit" class="button1" value="Hello">
<span class="arrow"></span>
</div>
</form>
```

and yet, when I delete the `.aaa` so the line looks like:

`.ie8 .button1{padding-right:4px;width:94px}`

The appearance of the button in IE8 changes from what it should look like - the version on the left in my picture, with a thinner width, to the right version on my picture - a wider width.

why is this happening, and how can I keep the appearance on the left side while deleting the unnecessary `.aaa` from the line?

Here's the full CSS:

```
.button-holder {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.button1 {
    padding: 4px 30px 4px 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.arrow:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


.arrow:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-top: 6px;
}
.arrow:before, .arrow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 11px;
    top: 6px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 3px;
}

.button1 {
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #FFE76E;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top,#F90,#FC0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 100.00%, 50.00% 0.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(255,198,1,1.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(255,248,162,1.00)));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#F90 0,#FC0 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(255,198,1,1.00) 0%,rgba(255,248,162,1.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(255,198,1,1.00) 0%,rgba(255,248,162,1.00) 100%);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #003!important;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0;
}

.button1:hover, .button1:focus {
    background-color: #FFC808;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top,#F90,#FC0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 100.00%, 50.00% 0.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(237,162,0,1.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(255,234,93,1.00)));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#F90 0,#FC0 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(237,162,0,1.00) 0%,rgba(255,234,93,1.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(237,162,0,1.00) 0%,rgba(255,234,93,1.00) 100%);
    text-decoration: none;
}


.ie8 .aaa .button1 {
    padding-right:4px;
    width:94px;
}
.ie8 .arrow:before,
.ie8 .arrow:after {
    background-color:transparent;
}
.ie8 .arrow:after { 
    font-size:40px;
    font-size:4rem;
    content:"›";
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height:11px;
    text-indent:-5px;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: If you don't use an 'aaa' class in your HTML, then you probably don't need that CSS line at all

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand regarding the .ie8 class (I'm using this in my code too), you should have a conditional comment somewhere in your code to actually apply that class to either the html, body, or some sort of parent element. Then you can target elements with CSS styles that apply specifically for ie8. For example, this is what I have in my code on the index page:

```
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
```

This is where I learned it from: [Louis Lazaris, ImpressiveWebs.com](http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie7-ie8-css-hacks/)

Comment: yes I'm including this inside the `head` (Edited my question to show it).

Comment: Sorry, got offline after last post. After reviewing your styles, I would say your `text-align: center` on .button1 is being inherited on your ie8. It's hard to debug without being able to mess with the code, but start there.